# ASP.NET MVC Shared Forms Auth Cookies Across Servers

Tags: asp.net, cookies, shared, formsauthentication

All,

We currently have subdomains across two boxes that require shared forms authentication cookies.

- Box1: Windows Server 2008 Standard/IIS 7
- Box2: Windows Server 2009 R2/IIS 7.5

We have already matched up all the forms auth values and machine key values in the web.config files, yet when we switch between apps, there is no auth cookie on the second machine. It doesn't matter which direction we go.

Are there issues sharing forms auth cookies between IIS 7 and 7.5?

Thanks,

B

Comment: Are you sure that cookies issued to domain rather than subdomains?

Comment: Victor, the cookies are set to .domain.com. We are pretty sure at this point that the issue is the boxes are different OSs and 32 to 64 bit. Once we moved the site from a 32 bit box to the 64 bit box on the same machine as the other apps, we had no problem with the form auth cookies.